# How to add a setter when there is a custom getter?

Tags: c#

I have to modify some existing code and am stumped on a getter setter.  How do I add a setter to this code?

```
public virtual string Sku
{
    get { return Product.Id.Trim(); }
}
```

Comment: Have you bothered looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do in the setter. If you want to assign a value to Product.Id then you should do something like this:

```
public virtual string Sku
{
    get { return Product.Id.Trim(); }
    set { Product.Id = value; }
}
```

In case you would like to set it to some private field you could do it like this:

```
private string _sku; 
public virtual string Sku
{
    get { return Product.Id.Trim(); }
    set { _sku = value; }
}
```

But then it is a bit akward that you have a setter to set a certain field, whereas when getting it you get a value from something completely different.

The most natural solution would seem to be:

```
private string _sku; 
public virtual string Sku
{
    get { return _sku.Trim(); }
    set { _sku = value; }
}
```

But I do not know the exact rules of your business logic.

Comment: thanks - but I just want to set it to a value - and not change the Product.Id

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but got a null error - turns out the parent object is not being populated correctly.